# How to enable DMA for all UARTs in RPi 4?

Tags: pi-4, uart

Using RPi 4B, image `2020-08-20-raspios-buster-armhf-lite.img` with kernel `5.4.51-v7l+`, but tried also to use Ubuntu Server with custom compiled kernel `5.4.83`.

I have trouble getting UARTs working with DMA for Raspberry PI4. There is kernel DMA initialization error seen in `dmesg` and if I understand correctly, UARTs is working without DMA.

I need to run UARTs at high speed (4M baud), so DMA is needed otherwise data is lost.

This is what I'm getting in `dmesg` when opening UART port (eg. by `minicom`):

```
[   65.809485] uart-pl011 fe201400.serial: no DMA platform data
[   72.853570] uart-pl011 fe201600.serial: no DMA platform data
```

I added following lines at `config.txt` end - I need to use custom clock to support 4MBPS and UARTs 0,2,3,5.

```
init_uart_clock=64000000
dtoverlay=disable-bt
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=uart2
dtoverlay=uart3
dtoverlay=uart5
```

Question: How to get all UARTs working with DMA for RPi 4b?

Edit:
Tried also with older kernel `5.2.21-v7l+` , same result

Comment: is [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57845) relevant to your question?

Comment: No, this says about RPI3 and older, which used BCM2835. RPi 4 is using BCM2711 which have DMA for UARTs (at least as stated in documentation)

Comment: No worries, I missed that point in that link :p